# Kindle2.0 hide soft key menu bar

Tags: java, android, kindle-fire

Am doing an application in KindleFire 2.0 , in my activity am displaying the application in the full screen mode. But I can still see the soft menu bar. Is there any way to hide the menu bar ? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

there's a couple of options - the Fire has a "full screen" mode which leaves a drag handle visible to get the on-screen soft keys back with a single tap, or what they call the ICS full screen mode which hides everything (you tap to bring back the drag handle then tap the drag handle to bring back the menus)

https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/cx-guidelines.html#Fullscreen